# How can i completely remove a jquery function after (window).resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a function.
Which after resize the viewport, i want to remove the function completely.
The off() method only remove the code inside scroll event.
When i'm resizing viewport, it's keep print out "this is still execute after resize".
Can i remove "myFunction" completely after resize the viewport with or without destroy my function?

```
function myFunction(ele) {
    myArray = [];
    this.num1 = $.each(ele, function(){
        var posx = ele.offset().top;
        myArray.push(pos);
        console.log('this is still execute after resize');
        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            // abcxyz
        });
    });
}

var target = $('p');
var run = new myFunction(target);

$(window).on('resize',function(){
    console.log("resized");
    $(window).off('scroll', myFunction(target));
});
```

Comment: Just use a global variable/flag and change it on windows resize. Since it is a global, you can use it inside of your function.

Comment: Note your function doesnt return anything so `run = new myFunction(...)` and `off('scroll', myFunction(target))` are meaningless. Also off() expects the function reference, ie leave off the parenthesis `off('scroll', myFunction)`  or just the event name `off('scroll')`. Just note `off('scroll', myFunction)` still wouldnt work as you never use myFunction as an event handler

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around for delay checking using timer because there is no exact resize event as you are looking for. If you stops for 500ms then resize function calls. This may helps you

```
function myFunction(ele) {
myArray = [];
this.num1 = $.each(ele, function(){
    var posx = ele.offset().top;
    myArray.push(pos);
    console.log('this is still execute after resize');
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        // abcxyz
    });
});
}

var target = $('p');
var run = new myFunction(target);

var listenForStop = (function () {
    var timers = {};
    return function (callback, ms, uId) {
        if (timers[uId]) {
            clearTimeout(timers[uId]);
        }
        timers[uId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    listenForStop(function () {
        $(window).off('scroll', myFunction(target));
    }, 500, "unique");
});
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it.

Comment: My pleasure @BaoPharm. If it works for you then upvote for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply overide it to 'undefined' after resize.

```
function myFunction(ele) {
    myArray = [];
    this.num1 = $.each(ele, function(){
        var posx = ele.offset().top;
        myArray.push(pos);
        console.log('this is still execute after resize');
        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            // abcxyz
        });
    });
}

var target = $('p');
var run = new myFunction(target);



  $(window).on('resize',function(){
        console.log("resized");
     if (typeof(myFunction) == "function"){
myFunction = undefined;
} 
    });
```

Edit:

What I suggest if what you need to reuse after it is to have the original function as backup. Then use the "power" of JS where **functions are variables**.
Here the code you can try:

```
    function myFunctionBackup(ele) {
    myArray = [];
    this.num1 = $.each(ele, function(){
        var posx = ele.offset().top;
        myArray.push(pos);
        console.log('this is still execute after resize');
        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            // abcxyz
        });
    });
}

var target = $('p');
var myFunction = myFunctionBackup;
myFunction(target);

  $(window).on('resize',function(){
        console.log("resized");
     if (typeof(myFunction) == "function"){
myFunction = undefined;
} 
    });

// When you want to return original simply do:
myFunction = myFunctionBackup;
```

Comment: What error you see?¿ I edited post to override to undefined only if myFunction is defined as function. It is simple code. Maybe there is an error in the code but "myFunction = undefined" part can't fail.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I will try it tomorrow and let you know if it's work.

Comment: This is worked now. It's completely destroy my function, do you anyway i can call it back, in case i need to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

to use the `.off()` function you must first instantiate the event with the `.on()` function follow example

```
function myFunction(ele) {
    myArray = [];
    this.num1 = $.each(ele, function(){
        var posx = ele.offset().top;
        myArray.push(pos);
        console.log('this is still execute after resize');
        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            // abcxyz
        });
    });
}

var target = $('p');
var run = new myFunction(target);

$(function(){
   $(window).on('scroll', myFunction(target));
});

$(window).on('resize',function(){
    console.log("resized");
    $(window).off('scroll', myFunction(target));
});
```

Comment: thanks. But this method trigger $.each everytime i scroll.
i don't really know if it's affect my site perfomance, i don't want if it does.